# An error occurred while installing racc (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Getting the following error while running bundle

```
An error occurred while installing racc (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install racc -v '1.6.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: if you have this issue when you tried to creaate a rails proyect with this command  rails new blog,  my suggestion is choice other one of rails framework, choose a newer version from here https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions and try again please

Answer (score 23):

I got the same error. I tried the following and the error's gone. Hopefully it can help you.

1. Update `ruby` to [the latest version 2.7.0p0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/) using:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ruby-full build-essential
   ```
2. Re-run `bundle install`

Answer (score 2):

For me (MacOS Sonoma 14.0) the root issue ended up being [this "Failed to build gem native extension" problem](https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/3372). The solution was:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then click yes to download.

You might also want to check that you've agreed to the Xcode license.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. If anyone else has a similar problem and wants to understand the issue deeper: the thing is, to compile a native Ruby extension it needs the C standard library (normally also available in your search path). It includes such headers as stdio.h, stdlib.h, etc. Installing Xcode CLI tools also installs the library into the search path for you so the native extensions can use the stdlib headers.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know the root issue, so thank you [Dmytro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3242031/dmytro-hutsuliak). The C standard library would be a much smaller download than the Xcode CLI tools, which as I recall is several gigs in size. So presumably there's a more space-efficient way to solve this problem, if we cared to.