# Failed to run a bundle install because there was an error installing racc (1.6.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle

I'm trying to run a `bundle install` on my rails app, and getting this error message:

```
An error occurred while installing racc (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install racc -v '1.6.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I proceeded to run `gem install racc -v '1.6.0'` and it got me:

```
The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
```

I was reading this article here:

[An error occurred while installing racc (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70398847/an-error-occurred-while-installing-racc-1-6-0-and-bundler-cannot-continue)

and ran `brew install ruby-full build-essential` but getting this error message:

```
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Anyone know how I can successfully run a `bundle install`?

Comment: What operating system? I'm guessing MacOS, and you need to install XCode.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.